# Django haystack - icontains not working

Tags: django, elasticsearch, filter, django-haystack

I have a field in my index as

```
title = indexes.CharField(model_attr='title')
```

So When I am querying like

```
SearchQuerySet().filter(title__icontains='text').models(MyModel)
```

this doesn't return the exact results as expected.

Expected: This should return all the objects which matches 'text' with their title.

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is title__icontains ? can you print the query you're sending ?

Comment: @blackmamba In the question itself there is a query which I am writing. That query returns empty list.